# Andoird - FFMPEG add time stamps or text on recorded video In Android

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg

Hi I am trying to add time stamps in recored video using andorid but can't able to do.
I am using `ffmpeg` library for that implementation `com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2`

My command is:

```
commandArray = new String[]{"-i", inputVideoPath, "-vf", "drawtext=fontfile=ostrich-regular.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontsize=24:",
                        "-codec:a", "copy", outputPath};
```

But app got stuck in `onProgress()` method.

// here is my whole code below

```
FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this);
        try {
            //Load the binary
            ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                }
            });
        } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
            // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
        }
        try {
            // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
            String outputPath = "";
            outputPath = getAppDir() + "/video_compress.mp4";

            String[] commandArray = new String[]{};

                commandArray = new String[]{"-i", inputVideoPath, "-vf", "drawtext=fontfile=ostrich-regular.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontsize=24:",
                        "-codec:a", "copy", outputPath};

            for (String i : commandArray) {
                System.out.println("Starting process " + i);
            }
            final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoActivity.this);
            ffmpeg.execute(commandArray, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    Log.e("FFmpeg", "onStart");
                    dialog.setMessage("Compressing... please wait");
                    dialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(String message) {
                    Log.e("FFmpeg onProgress? ", message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {
                    Log.e("FFmpeg onFailure? ", message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String message) {
                    Log.e("FFmpeg onSuccess? ", message);
                }


                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Log.e("FFmpeg", "onFinish");
                    if (dialog.isShowing())
                        dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
        }
```

Comment: put more code so I can understand?

Comment: File out put path -->                                                                                                     
String outputPath = "";
            outputPath = getAppDir() + "/video_compress.mp4";
   String[] commandArray = new String[]{};
now this command for adding text                                                                                           commandArray = new String[]{"-i", inputVideoPath, "-vf", "drawtext=fontfile=ostrich-regular.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontsize=24:",
                        "-codec:a", "copy", outputPath};